# Discord does not start

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, games

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit.  Discord used to work for me but no longer does.  I get these errors:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ discord
/snap/discord/69/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/adam/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

I have already tried the following:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor libgail-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libatk-adaptor is already the newest version (2.26.2-1).
libgail-common is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What  permissions does /home/adam/.config/user-dirs.dirs have? I think there might be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to work.  I had to re-download Discord: https://discordapp.com/download, then run these commands:

`sudo dpkg -i discord-0.0.5.deb`:

```
root@adam-desktop:/home/adam/Downloads# dpkg -i discord-0.0.5.deb
Selecting previously unselected package discord.
(Reading database ... 253573 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack discord-0.0.5.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package discord (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 discord
```

Notice the error, so run the next command: `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
root@adam-desktop:/home/adam/Downloads# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc++1 libc++abi1
Suggested packages:
  clang
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc++1 libc++abi1
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 240 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libc++abi1 amd64 6.0-2 [56.7 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libc++1 amd64 6.0-2 [183 kB]
Fetched 240 kB in 0s (781 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libc++abi1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 253662 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc++abi1_6.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc++abi1:amd64 (6.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc++1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libc++1_6.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc++1:amd64 (6.0-2) ...
Setting up libc++abi1:amd64 (6.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc++1:amd64 (6.0-2) ...
Setting up discord (0.0.5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ..
```

Comment: If you want to make your answer look like instruction, then edit and with exact `sudo ...` installation steps (without console output of every command).

Answer (score 1):

You need grant discord some permissions if you installed it from the Ubuntu/Snap store.

Open the installation page:

[image]

[image]

I granted all the permissions. You can try granting the permissions you want and check if it works. If you don't care then just grant all the permissions.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked for me.